# Adding title to li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<ul style="max-height: 400px;" class="dropdown-list-items current-list">
    <li class="dropdown-list-item unselectable  disabled " data-list-item-value="144" data-level-name="undefined" role="presentation">
        <span class="list-item-description text-ellipsis">1 Week</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a `title` attribute to the specific `li` element. I have many `li` elements in entire HTML inside the `ul` element. I have this javascript/jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-list-item.unselectable.disabled option[data-list-item-value="144"]').attr('title', 'testing titles');
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. When I directly add a `title` to the HTML, it appears on mouse over. However, I don't want to write `title` directly to the HTML. Is my script malformed or incorrect? Or am I missing something else?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43mz84uk/1/)

Comment: where is that `option[data-list-item-value="144"]` ?

Comment: @c-smile It's supposed to be selecting another attribute. I saw some example online somewhere using `option`, so I might have misunderstood the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used bad selector,

```
$('.dropdown-list-item.unselectable.disabled[data-list-item-value="144"]').attr('title', 'testing titles');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/43mz84uk/3/

Your selector try to find `option` inside `li`, you had to have HTML like:

```
<li class="dropdown-list-item unselectable disabled">
    <option data-list-item-value="144"><!-- << to this option you tried to set title -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('li[data-list-item-value="144"].dropdown-list-item.unselectable.disabled').attr('title', 'testing titles');
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/43mz84uk/2/)

In your html there is not `option` tag